# Constant Figure Axis Range on GUI in Matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, plot

I have a working slider in my Matlab plot (GUI) that callbacks the different column of the same matrix (Tlast), the code below:

```
n=length(Tlast(:,1)); h=1:n; h=(1.05/n)*h';

slmin=1; slmax=size(Tlast,2);

plot(h,Tlast(:,1)); 

hsl = uicontrol('Style','slider','Min',slmin,'Max',slmax,...
'SliderStep',[1 1]./(slmax-slmin),'Value',1,...
'Position',[5 5 200 20]);

set(hsl,'Callback',@(hObject,eventdata) 
plot(h,Tlast(:,round(get(hObject,'Value')))) )
```

The problem is that each call with slide move changes the x and y axis limits. Would any of you tell me how to fix the axis limits at each condition (callback from slider) - i.e. y axis constant as 40 to 90?

Thanks in advance. Regards.

Comment: Take a look at these two articles: [1](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/change-axis-limits-of-graph.html), [2](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html). In the 2nd one, look specifically at the different examples.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the limits of the current axis as under

```
xlim([xmin xmax])
ylim([ymin ymax])
```

you can also use axis function

```
axis([xmin xmax ymin ymax])
```

Comment: I tried using axis function but whenever I move the slider; again my axis changes as to the new data range. I added _hold on_: this solves my problem (axis stay same) however this time all of my plots (by every change at the slider) stays at the plot area.

Comment: you can use `xlim` and `ylim` after the `plot` function to limit your current axes. you have to call these in your slider event handler

Answer (score 0):

The following gives your more flexibility to control your axes:

```
xlim([xmin xmax]);
ylim([ymin ymax]);
set(gca, 'XTick', [xmin:xmax]);
set(gca, 'YTick', [ymin:ymax]);
set(gca,'fontweight','demi','fontsize',giveafontsize)
```